# How to get a similar value in Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a table of two columns

```
Col1  Col2
A        1
A        2
A        3
B        1
B        2
B        3
```

Output I need is like this

```
Col1    Col2
A       1
A       1,2
A       1,2,3
B       1
B       1,2
B       1,2,3
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which database are you actually using, MySQL or Oracle?  They're not the same thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It for learn purpose. I need to know in both but mostly in oracle.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution which would work for MySQL.  It uses a correlated subquery in the select clause to group concatenate together `Col2` values.  The logic is that we only aggregate values which are less than or equal to the current row, for a given group of records sharing the same `Col1` value.

```
SELECT
    Col1,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t2.Col2 ORDER BY t2.Col2) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.Col2 <= t1.Col2 AND t1.Col1 = t2.Col1) Col2
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    t1.Col1,
    t1.Col2;
```

[image]

### Demo

Here is the same query in Oracle:

```
SELECT
    Col1,
    (SELECT LISTAGG(t2.Col2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t2.Col2) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.Col2 <= t1.Col2 AND t1.Col1 = t2.Col1) Col2
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    t1.Col1,
    t1.Col2;
```

### Demo

Note that the only real change is substituting `LISTAGG` for `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with s (Col1, Col2) as (
select 'A', 1 from dual union all
select 'A', 2 from dual union all
select 'A', 3 from dual union all
select 'B', 1 from dual union all
select 'B', 2 from dual union all
select 'B', 3 from dual)
select col1, ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(col2, ','), ',') path
from s
start with col2 = 1
connect by prior col2 = col2 - 1 and prior col1 = col1;

C PATH
- ----------
A 1
A 1,2
A 1,2,3
B 1
B 1,2
B 1,2,3

6 rows selected.
```